# UniqueValueRenderer and ClassBreaksRenderer configuration

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#, arcgis-engine

So I can create one of these renderers based on parameters I let the user set. Some parameter combinations either create invalid conditions or no conditions at all - missing data, too many breaks or too few, and so on. This obviously unacceptable. I've considered doing what the desktop product does and display the list of breaks and let the user fiddle with the parameters until they do something useful. Has anyone done that? Is there a sample somewhere on how to do that? If not can someone offer advice on either doing that or suggest another way to ensure that a renderer "works?"

Comment: Do you have access to a charting control that allows you to display a histogram?

Comment: At first I thought you were talking about IChartRenderer (which I haven't implemented yet!) But I actually suspect that you are reccommending that I display the results of the classification in a dialog that uses a histogram, Is that correct?

Comment: I like that idea but after spending time using the Desktop product I am a little nonplussed. It seems that I can go into that tool and set parameters and watch the listview fill up with data but when I OK the dialog what appears on the map may be what I expect or may be nothing at all. Is ArcGIS programming the same as running with scissors? (I'm currently resigned to COM controls outliving the cockroaches. Anyone want to take that bet?)